How can we find the position vector of the centroid G in terms of a, b, and c?

The problem
Consider a triangle ABC. Find, with proof, the position vector of its centroid G, with
respect to the position vectors of A, B and C. Suppose the side lengths of the triangle are
a =BC, b=CA and c=AB.
Find the position vector of the incenter I of triangle ABC.


My thoughts on it:
Okay, so according to theory, the centroid of a triangle with coordinates A(x1, y1), B(x2, y2), C(x3, y3) is:
$$
D = \left( \frac{x_1 + x_2 + x_3}{3}, \frac{y_1 + y_2 + y_3}{3} \right) \in \mathbb{R}^2
$$
Not entirely sure how I am supposed to prove this in:
$$ \mathbb{R}^2$$, let alone in: $$ \mathbb{R}^n$$

If you have any ideas as to how I should approach this problem, do let me know. I am not really sure if I am even considering it properly currently. My thanks in advance.


What's your definition of centroid?

@Intelligentipauca well, the centroid of a triangle is the point of intersection of the medians of a triangle.

A theorem in elementary geometry states that the centroid divides each median in the proportion $2:1$.

The lengths of the sides are irrelevant.
Let $\vec r$ be the centroid of the triangle. Then, since the vectors from $\vec r$ to the vertices must sum to zero, we get $$(\vec A-\vec r)+(\vec B-\vec r)+(\vec C-\vec r)=\vec 0\implies \vec A+\vec B+\vec C=3\vec r\implies \vec r=\frac{1}{3}(\vec A+\vec B+\vec C)$$
where $\vec A$, $\vec B$ and $\vec C$ are the position vectors of the vertices.

Oh, I see what you have done. Thanks a lot man, I appreciate that!

@BudaGabriel-Christian You're welcome. Notice that this works for any $k$ points in $\mathbb R^n$.

Let $M$ be the midpoint of $BC$.
A theorem in elementary geometry states that the intersection point $D$ of the medians lies at $2/3$ of the distance between $A$ and $M$.
Then:
$$
D=A+{2\over3}(M-A)={1\over3}A+{2\over3}M
={1\over3}A+{2\over3}{B+C\over2}={1\over3}A+{1\over3}B+{1\over3}C.
$$

Woah, this one looks crazy complicated.

@BudaGabriel-Christian Hence I gather your definition of centroid is NOT the intersecting point of the medians but the point whose vector distances from the vertices sum to zero. If I had known I would have avoided answering.
